# Synchronized message passing with Prism

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

In our prism application we need to load a module to the centre pane when the user clicks an item in a tree(seperate module). The module in the centre pane(say designer module) can open a file and display itself if it is given a path. How can I pass the path of the file to this module?
For example

in Designer module

```
public DesignerViewModel(DataAccess dataAccess)// This will be injected
{
}


//The following class can create the model objects using the IDataService for getting data from remote location
public DataAccess(IDataService service)//this will be injected 
{
}
```

The data access object is local to the Designer module, so I wouldnt like to expose it to outside the module. So the registration is done in the module

```
public class DesignerModule : IModule
 {
       public void Initialize()
        {
            var container = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnityContainer>();
            container.RegisterType<Object, DesignerView>("DesignerUI");
            container.RegisterType<DataAccess>();             
        }
   }
```

IDataService is registered in the application level

```
  public class BootStrapper : UnityBootstrapper
  { 
       protected override void ConfigureContainer()
       {
            base.ConfigureContainer();
            Container.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>();
       }
  }
```

Note that IDataService is a singleton for the entire app. I cannot pass the path of file which is specific to a module instance in IDataService. Note that you can open any number of modules in the centre pane as you like, just click on a tree item->tree will fire an event with the selected item id->app will find out a path corresponding to the item id and invoke the module.

How will I pass the path when I say _regionManager.AddToRegion("CenterRegion", DesignerModule); Prism will do all the dependency injections beautifully, but how to pass the path is a big question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer from my colleague.The parameters can be overriden with your own objects when you call Resolve(). So create the object which is going to be injected, populate it and pass with the Resolve<>() with ParameterOverride. Search for ParameterOverride in google for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) to exchange with messages beetwen modules.
Each module subscribe to EventAggregator.
While you open a module you can send to host control notification about newborn.
Host control send response back with initialization data.

```
public class MessageEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<Message>{}

internal class MessageReceiver
{
    private readonly MessageEvent _evt;
    private readonly string _myId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    internal MessageReceiver(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _evt = eventAggregator.GetEvent<MessageEvent>();
        _evt.Subscribe(Receive, true);

        _evt.Publish(new Message { Source = _myId, Command = Message.Commands.WhoIAm });
    }
    public void Receive(Message message)
    {
        switch (message.Command)
        {
            case Message.Commands.WhoIAm:
                _evt.Publish(
                    new Message
                    {
                        Destination = message.Source,
                        Command = Message.Commands.Initialize,
                        MessageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("init data")
                    });
                break;
            case Message.Commands.Initialize:
                if (message.Destination == _myId)
                {
                    //init
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
public class Message
{
    public enum Commands { Initialize, WhoIAm }

    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public Commands Command { get; set; }
    public byte[] MessageData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Radik-this is not exactly what I want. Note that Module creation itself is because of an event from a tree module which includes the path information. This event will be handled by the main application and the mainapp will create a Designer Module in the center pane of the application. I would prefer passing the path information at the point of module instance creation.